# Add String row to TableView in JAVA FX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I can't find a way to add a simple "String" row to my tableView.
In fact i can add a row but its content is **not visible** ...

Here is my code:

```
@FXML
private TableView<String> table; 

@FXML
private TableColumn<String, String> table2;

public ObservableList<String> getLanes()
{
    ObservableList<String> lanes=FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    lanes.add("TEST");

    return lanes;
}
```

Then:

```
table.setItems(getLanes()); //Not working
```

and

```
table.getItems().add("TEST"); //Not working
```

But without success.
I read [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911647/populating-tableview-in-javafx) and [that](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm) as well as other documentations but it did not help me to do it in this simple way.

**EDIT:**

Adding this line solved my problem:

```
table2.setCellValueFactory(param -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(param.getValue()));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple way to add data to columns in JavaFX TableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31318713/simple-way-to-add-data-to-columns-in-javafx-tableview)

Comment: Have you defined a `setCellValueFactory()` for your column?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha  No i did not.Because even with many examples i do not know what it is for and how it should be used ... If you can give me advices on that ...

Comment: What about two columns? `private TableColumn<String, String> name; private TableColumn<String, String> lastName;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simple application where we are trying to load a single value into a TableView column. It also shows how to set a `cellValueFactory()` on a table column.

```
tableColumn.setCellValueFactory(param -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(param.getValue()));
```

**MCVE**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringWrapper;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        TableView<String> tableView = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<String, String> tableColumn = new TableColumn<>("Name");

        tableColumn.setCellValueFactory(param -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(param.getValue()));

        tableView.getColumns().add(tableColumn);
        ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Itachi");
        tableView.setItems(items);

        VBox root = new VBox(tableView);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 275);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Adding simply this line resolved my problem: `table2.setCellValueFactory(param -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(param.getValue()));`

Comment: I'm still curious why people prefer `ReadOnlyStringWrapper` to it's superclass `SimpleStringProperty`. `ReadOnlyStringWrapper` is not a unmodifiable property...

Comment: To keep things immutable ;)

Comment: Well, param.getValue() is not defined